# DefaultTableModel doesn't show columns

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, jtableheader

I have problem with DefaultTableModel it won't show me my columns in table, there is a part of code:

```
JTable table = new JTable() {
        public boolean isCellEditable(int data, int columnNames) {
            return false;
        }
    };
    String columnNames[] = new String[] { "First Name", "Last Name", "Sport", "# of Years", "Vegetarian", "asd", "asd" };
    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(0, 0);
    dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);

    table.setModel(dtm);
for (Reservation r : reservation) {
        rez.add(new Reservation(r.getID(), r.getA(),    r.getB(), r.getC(), r.getD(), r.getE(), r.getF()));

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rez.size(); i++) {
        int id = rez.get(i).getID();
        String l = rez.get(i).getA();
        String w = rez.get(i).getB();
        String z = rez.get(i).getC();
        String o = rez.get(i).getD();
        String d = String.valueOf(rez.get(i).getE());
        String g = rez.get(i).getF();
        dtm.addRow(new Object[] { id, l, w, z, d,o,g });

    }


    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(dtm);
    add(table);

}
```

Im trying to make a dynamic table. Data will be from data base (posgreSQL) using hibernate, and thats fine, it work's but I cant see a column names from

```
String columnNames[] = new String[] { "First Name", "Last Name", "Sport", "# of Years", "Vegetarian", "asd", "asd" };
```

Don't care about names of columns and name of getters i changed it for this post.

In addition I can't make it scrollable:

```
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(dtm);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how this would be able to compile

```
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(dtm);
add(table);
```

`dtm` is an instance of `DefaultTableModel` so it should never be possible to pass it to a `JScrollPane`,

Instead you should be using

```
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table);
add(sp);
```

See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

Comment: Column names are more important for me :)

Comment: @GumovvySteven Have you actually tried the above suggestion. The linked tutorial clearly states that _ you are using a table without a scroll pane, then you must get the table header component and place it yourself._ . So by using the scrollpane correctly, the column names will appear

Comment: And the table to the scroll pane, volia, column headers

Comment: Sorry, Im in work so i cant test it, I will try it at home. Thanks :)

Comment: I made it, without effect ;(

Answer (score 2):

Add the table rather than the `TableModel` to the `JScrollPane`

```
add(new JScrollPane(table));
```

Comment: Column names are more important for me :)